# moving EDMX file to new project caused: System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 project.
I've created edmx file on the class library project that holds the model.

now I've created another class library called it shared and moved the edmx file over there.
resolved some issues, everything compiles, but it can't find the connection string resource at runtime.

I've copied the ConnectionString part of the Web.Config to the main file, the old class library app.config file and the new class library app.config file.

Still get this error:

> System.Data.MetadataException: Unable
>   to load the specified metadata
>   resource.
>
> Line 75:         public myProjdb() :
>   base("name=myProjdb", "MyProjdb")

in the MyProj.Designer.cs file.

Any Idea how to resolve this issue ?

Is there a better way to store connection string data ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use the same model in other projects if you use a connection string that includes the assembly name.  In the connection string you have in web.config, try changing the `*` in the connection string, from

```
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=...
```

to something like this:

```
metadata=res://ClassLibrary1/Model1.csdl|res://ClassLibrary1/Model1.ssdl|res://ClassLibrary1/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=...
```

Comment: did you copy the edmx file, or move it?  is it in the root of the project, or in a subfolder?

Comment: I've put it in subfolder - maybe this is the issue ? checking.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the subfolder. it doesn't need to be changed to the assembly name (moved it back to *). Is there a way to put it in a subfolder ?

Comment: If the model is in a subfolder, the folder name should be in the connection string, something like this:  `//ClassLibrary1/Subfolder.Model1.csdl|...`.  I think this is because the folder becomes part of the namespace that the model is located in.